# Show examples of good and bad questions

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Stack Overflow's rules have grown very complex and often counter-intuitive over the years. That doesn't mean they don't exist for a reason, but grokking SO's culture can be really tough even for newcomers who ask in good faith. The problem is multiplied for non-native speakers of English.

Many people learn much, much better from real-world examples than from a huge list of abstract rules. I know - I'm one of them.

To better guide these people, we should show a **curated and annotated list of good and bad example questions**. This list should be extremely easy to reach - it could for example be a second tab on the "How to ask" page. It should be a separate page, maybe with questions listed in 2 columns.

Each example is a full question, with an explanatory "what's wrong with this question?" paragraph underneath. The paragraph will be very curt and to the point.

> **What's wrong with this question?**
>
> It's a "shopping question" asking for a product recommendation. Questions like this are off topic on Stack Overflow: they frequently lead to low-quality content and subjective opinions.

etc. etc.

Thinking of the extreme problem cases  is easy. Too vague,  Gorilla vs. Shark / Shopping question, Duplicate / too basic, Multiple questions in one, Wall of code... But we should also cover the more subtle cases where a question looks perfectly intelligent, but is not a good fit for the site.

Thinking of *good* examples is less easy - I can think of

- Great title
- Question body giving a lot of detail, but not too much
- Good structure (introduction / question)
- On topic
- Not too long
- Not too short

The list should be curated by staff.

Ideally, there would be example questions on a per-tag basis, at least for the big tags.

A "before" / "after" view might also work: How do I fix a problematic question?

The examples should be **linkable** so they can be used in communicating with authors of problematic questions. I can't see a way to misuse this in a rude way as there was with "What Stack Overflow is not".

Also, I think this would be a great help for dealing with the language barrier. An example is going to be way easier to grasp than a thousand words if you have trouble parsing the language in the first place.

> Updated and fixed small errors (in lieu of a bounty)... I still think this would be worthwhile doing - now more than ever....

Comment: I assume you're aiming only for the worst of the worst with your bad examples? Because if the language barrier is a problem, it might be difficult to grasp the subtle differences that sometimes exist between a good on-topic question and one that doesn't belong.

Comment: @Bart That's a good point. It shouldn't be *only* the clearly bad cases - it's the subtleties that are so hard to grasp around here sometimes. We've all seen intelligent people get frustrated with SO because they don't get around those. A list of examples would absolutely have to contain examples that *look* great, but are a bad fit nevertheless for a less-than-obvious reason. Maybe even with a "before" / "after" view that shows how to fix it

Comment: Great idea, but I'm very pessimistic about people taking the effort to read them. I think the problem is not the lack of documentation on how to write a good question or the availability of good examples (if you're willing to look around for a while). The problem is that many people just don't seem to be aware of the fact that their question could possibly fail any quality standards, so why take the effort to make it better? Maybe if your idea would turn into some good question contest (with extra rep, yay!) some people _might_ wake up.

Comment: @Gert we'll never reach those who don't read *anything* - they'll eventually be shut out by the quality filter, and good riddance. But I'm convinced there is a demographic of reasonable, good-faith potential users who can grow into productive members once they "get it". Those are who this would address. (Also, running into a question ban may indeed cause some people to wake up, and develop an interest in how things work)

Comment: But there seem to be so many of them (the non-readers) * sigh *. Nevertheless I'd like to give it a try and I'd love to cooperate in it.

Comment: For question body, I suggest: "1. Explanation of what is attempted (probably with code snippet). 2. Expected/desired result. 3. Actual result."

Comment: +1, for catering to good-faith new users instead of ones who are unsaveable.  We don't do that enough in our attempts to improve new user flow.

Comment: +1 I support this. I also shamelessly nominate one of my questions to be on the list as a good question in the javascript/jquery tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118057/crazy-behavior-in-jquery-date-picker

Comment: Declining this because I think Laura's answer nails the real solution: **strive to make *every question you see* a good example;** there's a much better chance of someone new finding a long-tail question in their area of interest and learning from that than of them finding and reading a small, curated list.

Comment: @Shog9 No matter how hard we try, not every question is going to be a model question. The goal here is to make users learn good and bad questions, not good and bad code.

Comment: @Knights: of course not; but those are the examples that most folks will actually *see*, and thus the ones that'll actually influence them. [Here are your greatest hits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits?userId=1131435) - they don't need to be perfect, but are they *good* examples? If not, there's where you can start...

Comment: `strive to make every question you see a good example` ok, but I'll need one  of [these](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_pPsuc9rvU4Y/S-nZaYfhbnI/AAAAAAAABlg/VqXK-eqXd_4/s1600/flamethrower.jpg) for that

Comment: It's  declined for the same reason "what stackovrflow is not" was deleted after many people contribute to the subject, it just reduces the income to SE.

Comment: why did this get bounced? Because we're not showing people enough non-functional walls of text already, now they have to read 20 distinct examples as well?

Comment: @JeffAtwood the idea wasn't to force them go through each example before asking their first question or something. Rather to have something to refer to when running into problems, as a replacement/alternative to the textual help

Answer (score 18):

This is a massive amount of work to treat a symptom rather than a disease.

Rather than having the community pour energy into curating a massive list of questions that, to be quite frank, new users will be no more likely to read than they are likely to read the FAQ, there are two things that should happen to get to the heart of the problem.

### I. Better, clearer guidance in the infrastructure.

Simply put, we (SE, Inc.) need to make our complex rules more understandable. Our current guidance to new users is spread across MSO, child metas, blog posts, the FAQ, and various other pages like How to Ask and How to Answer, which are difficult to find again even when you're trying.

To remedy this problem, we're working on a new, consolidated Help center - I'll be posting more about this on meta in the coming weeks, but the basic goal is to make a comprehensive AND comprehensible set of reference material that new users can browse and experienced users can easily link to.

The second major problem is that our guidance sometimes uses jargon that doesn't make sense to a drive-by user, or we use common words with a meaning that is different and very specific to our site. We'll be trying to avoid that in the new copy.

### II. Demonstrate by example -- not *listing* examples.

This is a community effort, which I'm hoping will be well-received since you are suggesting a community effort as well. :)

I firmly believe that learning as you go is the best way to familiarize oneself with the Stack Exchange model. Documentation and guidelines are helpful for a better understanding of the nuances, philosophy, and background, but you really shouldn't need them to learn what a good question is (though you might need the reference material to understand *why* our definition of "good question" is what it is).

**The goal of Stack Exchange is to have EVERY question on the site be eligible for a "good question" list.**

I think that the solution is guidance on a per-post basis. Examples are nice, to be sure, but people will learn best when the example is *their own*. To that end, we should be encouraging people to provide helpful comments pointing to useful reference material or asking clarifying questions, or to suggest edits that clean up bad questions so that they meet our standards. A lot of people - IF they bother to look at this annotated list you're suggesting - will probably have trouble translating your examples to general principles that they can apply to their own questions.

Once we have a better Help center, it'll hopefully be easier to point people to a canonical instructional source of how to use the site. That generalized philosophy, combined with a concerted effort from experienced users to provide user-specific suggestions and guidance, should help us make big progress towards educating new users about our complicated but effective model of exchanging knowledge.

We do have a lot of mechanisms built in to deal with the people who deliberately make no effort to learn our system: downvotes, question bans, etc. deal with the worst offenders. For the people who just don't realize how we're different from other sites, better references, browsing the already great content here (people will gain an intuitive sense of what's good by seeing what types of questions have high scores; passive learning like that is important, too), and receiving specific suggestions for improvements will be a more natural way to learn than studying a list of example good and bad questions.

As a final note, I think that listing full questions that we *don't* want is a bad idea; I don't want people remembering those questions later, even on a subconscious level.

Comment: The help center sounds promising, looking forward to that, but... `to have EVERY question on the site be eligible for a "good question" list` every one of the 5.5 million of them, probably 80% of which are duplicates of each other?  I don't think that's a realistic goal.

Comment: "This is a massive amount of work to treat a symptom rather than a disease." Even if we allow for some rhetorical grandeur, that is simply wrong. _First_, it is not a "massive amount of work". It is a limited amount of work which can easily be quantified: The OP lists 5 typical problems ranging from "too vague" to "wall of code" and mentions the need to cover a few more subtle cases too. Add a couple of positive examples and we're done. _Secondly_, the OP doesn't propose to simply treat symptoms, but rather to teach people to fish, which is very different and much more constructive.

Comment: Also, I'm with @Pekka on this one - defining a goal like "... EVERY question on the site be eligible for a "good question" list" (your emphasis) sounds to me like it won't scale in any meaningful sense. Have you made any estimates or calculations of the effort needed to achieve that goal compared to the number of active participants in the community? If you have, it would be really nice if you could share it.

Comment: The help center sounds promising (and frankly a bit like the "new user chat room" that I proposed in [this extremely controversial answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179016/218334)). That said, I feel that the infrastructure already provides an enormous amount of guidance. I think it's much more important to work on encouraging the community to be a little more proactive in helping new members learn, which I think is what you're suggesting here, but based on how many downvotes my answer received, I'm not sure how receptive the community is to that idea.

Comment: "The second major problem is that our guidance sometimes uses jargon that doesn't make sense to a drive-by user, or we use common words with a meaning that is different and very specific to our site. We'll be trying to avoid that in the new copy." -- this is an important point. Is this just going to be in the help center copy, or will it be a more extensive wording change? (I ask because I think some of the close reasons themselves, especially "not constructive", use really specialized jargon that doesn't align well with common usage).

Comment: @BenLee Obviously, we are not rewriting every word of copy across the whole network all at once. Eventually, maybe, but not just yet. ;) The major changes actively being worked on now are the Help pages and the close reasons. There are [several](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814) other [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732) posts [about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/) close reasons, with a few more changes still in the works. If you have other specific things you think we should prioritize, feel free to make a request here on MSO.

Comment: @Laura, thanks for the links. I'd already seen the 1st and 3rd of those, but that 2nd one is new to me -- and it sums up my feelings on the wording issue exactly!

Comment: The /ask page is ancient and needs to be rebuilt from scratch with better just in time contextual help based on who the user is and what they are doing. I worry that this new help center sounds suspiciously like the old help text that nobody read, either. This time it'll be different, I guess, but users won't read anything you put on the screen. At least not the ones who most need to.

Comment: @JeffAtwood You're totally right; we need to provide more just-in-time help, and the /ask page is almost certainly the most important place to do that. The new help center solves a different use case; I think the people who get burned most on our network are the new users who do genuinely try to figure out our system and just can't. If they're directed to (or find on their own) the help center, it should be a one-stop source of any reference/instructional material they need, which the current FAQ doesn't provide. That's definitely a small subset of users, but still important to address.

Comment: I've been wanting to add more contextual help throughout the site for a while now; it's a larger, more complex project that we don't have the resources to focus on right now, but it is definitely still on our minds (and to-do list).

Comment: @laura it becomes a game of percentages of percentages of percentages -- how many people is this *really* helping? Remember too that every single new Stack Overflow user is forced to click through the How to Ask page before their first question. (Try it yourself; create a new account then click Ask Question on SO.) You could do that network-wide, with a better consolidated help page, perhaps, if we can avoid wall o 'text. That would reach those willing to read and try, though these users already do well on the network IMO, so then the question again: *who is this really reaching?*

Answer (score 12):

Abusing the answer functionality to get better formatting of what could have been a comment. You can add that to your don'ts if you wish :-).

This is a great idea, and even if it will occasionally be misunderstood, misinterpreted, misused and a couple of other misses, it will still help nudge things a step forward.

Just a couple of thoughts for good examples of the down-to-earth variety:

- Break long paragraphs up into smaller units
- Capitalise sentences
- Spell check
- Reduce code to about 10 lines or less if possible

These are little things, but they help change the impression of a question from being gibberish to at least parseable. That may actually fend off a close vote or two. It is also fairly easy to show the difference in an example and sufficiently mechanical in nature to be practical also for non-native speakers.

Answer (score 12):

> A "before" / "after" view might also work

In many areas it might be worth using bad questions/answers that were later edited into great questions/answers for a direct side by side comparison.

**As in** - A closed question with -10 votes next to the same question edited and reopened with +10 votes.

This would not only show the value of editing, but would also help to show the value of taking the time to formulate a good question/answer and at the same time illuminate the possible consequences of a poor question/answer.