# How does Stack Overflow help beginners to prevent them from getting negative votes

Tags: discussion

Many of them are new for Stack Overflow. There are well and good procedures available for asking questions, but some may not able to ask what they think.

At that time they can get negative votes from experts, and it may cause hesitation for asking the next question.

How does Stack Overflow prevent this?

Comment: well I don't think that SO does that as everyone here giving answers want the best answer to be delivered. So they can't allow themselves not to give their reviews on each question or answer if it is wrong. And of course **EVERYONE HERE** get negative votes in the beginning.

Comment: Stack Overflow helps them by downvoting and voting to close. "Some may not able to ask what they think" – so nobody can answer such a question, correct?

Comment: Harsh downvotes on this question!! I think it's a very valid question and the number of downvotes it recieved really highlights the issue of angry, holier-than-thou SO users. The answer given is a good one, but I think that it could be pushed further and users could actively be shown examples of good and bad questions before they can publish their first one. :)
I'm all for helping people here without being nasty and condescending to them.

Comment: The downvotes are because you show no sign of having researched this issue i.e. by reading any previous questions on the subject. Nobody is being nasty here.

Comment: I agree it's unnecessary to downvote a question asked in a constructive spirit by a newish user for whom English is a second language. I'm all for having people do their research first, but Meta is a vast and confusing desert of tens of thousands of discussions.

Comment: @admrply http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296353/show-examples-of-good-and-bad-questions

Comment: it does not prevent this. And it has caused many people to get disgusted and move to quora. https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late and the likes...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple places for new users to learn about the system and how to ask a question:

- [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Jon Skeets "*Writing the perfect question*" (http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)
- [the "How to ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- ...

Also, when asking a question, there are multiple related questions popping up. Most of the questions of new users could have been solved by using either the search function on site or if the user had *at least tried* to research and have a look at those.