# Give first time askers real examples of bad questions before posting?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

So I've already seen this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296353/show-examples-of-good-and-bad-questions) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261867/can-we-automatically-guide-programming-newbies-to-the-tag-wikis-for-tutorials)

They are suggesting adding it to a separate curated list or a link to some other page (adding a link to it is probably not going to attract the attention of a new user). What I'm suggesting basically is that we show a page with 3 or 4 most common types of bad questions for first-time users, say guests and users with say, up to 3 questions.

This can be shown on a page before they submit, and need only be shown for new users or guests, and won't be shown once you get used to the site. It just needs to be 3 -4 examples so that a new user won't tend to skip too much of it, and we can see if this reduces the amount of bad question influx. We can even add another link to "See all the rules" for users that may then read it.

Why I'm suggesting this is that for a lot of new users, a concrete example of a bad question might be more effective than a list of rules. Some basic stuff I'm thinking of is stuff like "I want to do generic thing X plz provide code" or "How to use feature Y" where Y would be a simple well-documented piece of code or a question with code/data posted as an image.

I'm not saying this will deter all new users from adding bad questions, but it may reduce the number and it won't hurt to see if it does.

Comment: I like this in theory, however, I think it's just another page for new people to click through before posting their question. The people who are going to take the time to go through the Tour and FAQ will do it, those who aren't willing to do that will just skip over pages and go right to asking bad questions. Though that could just be my own pessimism, your idea might be worth a try, depending on how invasive it would be to implement.

Comment: I'm pretty skeptical.  It is like teaching somebody how to drive by showing him crash videos.  Not the way it is done, there are too many ways to do it wrong and the most likely outcome is you preferring to use the bus instead :)

Comment: @DavyM But it might prove more effective than expecting the user to go to another page. If a user sees a page with the submit post button at the bottom, they might just read through it. It wont bee too invasive on regular users, as it will be shown to guests and people with less than, say 3 questions. I personally find that people might be too lazy to read through all the rules on a different page, but might be more willing to see maybe 3 or 4 examples of bad questions.

Comment: @HansPassant true. In my mind, I was thinking of showing a bad question just like we show it on the page - with all the downvotes and all. As I said, this might deter at least some users, though not all. The shock value of bad questions might be better than a list of rules. Like anti-smoking adverts on cigarette packs showing tumors

Comment: It is already difficult for people to read beyond one or two paragraphs before they TL;DR out. Shoving examples in front of people is just as likely to be counterproductive - it may cause people to care even less about doing the right thing as they're pelted with so many signals that it turns into noise. The only true path that may have some effect is for people to make mistakes and get faced with the consequences. Having a decent canonical with examples on meta to refer to in the aftermath however, can be valuable.

Comment: Why, when they make their own example?